# firestore functions Error: Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I making firestore functions and I get this error in log

```
    import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

var defaultApp = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const firebase = admin.database();



module.exports.onUserStatusChange = functions.firestore.document('/status/{userId}').onUpdate((change,context) => {



    const newValue = change.after.data();
    console.log('new value',newValue);
    console.log('change',change);
    console.info('context',context)
    admin.firestore().collection('status')
    .where('state', '==', 'online')
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.docChanges.forEach(function(change) {
            console.info('change->',change.type)
            if (change.type === 'added') {
                var msg = 'User ' + change.doc.id + ' is online.';
                console.log(msg);
                // ...
            }
            if (change.type === 'removed') {
                var msg = 'User ' + change.doc.id + ' is offline.';
                console.log('removed',msg);
                // ...
            }
        });
    });
    return newValue;

});
```

I get this error because here I define the firebase in config

```
    var defaultApp = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
```

and not firestore,
but into the web of firebase I create Firestore database.
so I'm looking a way to connect my firestore to this file and work with firestore database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
var defaultApp = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
```

to this:

```
var defaultApp = admin.initializeApp();
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff